# In Spring LDAP, what happens when a pooled connection fails to successfully connect?

Tags: spring-ldap, pooling

I am using Spring LDAP (2.0.2.RELEASE) to interact with our AD environment.  I have integrated pooling within my applicationContext.xml.

In the [Java LDAP docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap.html) (section 3.4), it states

> If the LDAP provider cannot establish a connection within that period, it aborts the connection attempt

My question is: does spring handle a retry for this connection, or is there an error that occurs/thrown?  I know Spring utilizes many of the underlying JVM LDAP features, but I have yet to find anything specific in this area.

Pertinent pieces of my applicationContext:

```
<bean id="dirContextValidator" class="org.springframework.ldap.pool.validation.DefaultDirContextValidator" />

<bean id="exampleConnectionDetails" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource" scope="singleton">
    <property name="url" value="ldaps://ldap.example.com:636" />
    <property name="userDn" value="CN=LDAP_User,DC=example,DC=com" />
    <property name="password" value="superSecretPwd" />
    <property name="pooled" value="false"/>
    <property name="referral" value="follow"/>
</bean>

<bean id="exampleContextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.pool.factory.PoolingContextSource">
    <property name="contextSource" ref="exampleConnectionDetails" />
    <property name="dirContextValidator" ref="dirContextValidator" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000" />
    <property name="whenExhaustedAction" value="0" />

    <property name="minIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="15000" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="30000" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="7" />
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/pooling.html) for testOnBorrow states this,

> testOnBorrow: The indication of whether objects will be validated before being borrowed from the pool. If the object fails to validate, it will be dropped from the pool, and an attempt to borrow another will be made.

I understand, Spring will attempt to make another connection in the event of an failure.